# Block allocation

Tags: c#, c++, memory, allocation

Is it better to pre-allocate (for example) 100KB of memory (in the heap) but then only go on to use 60KB, or is it better to allocate each byte as you need it?

My question arises from reading this blog:
http://deplinenoise.wordpress.com/2012/10/20/toollibrary-memory-management-youre-doing-it-wrong/

Comment: It depends, what comes at a premium here? Is it memory, time (allocating heap space takes time after all), or code clarity.  If allocating some number of extra bytes is never going to hurt you then just allocate it all at once.

Comment: Of course, in C++ STL (for example) the vector class allocates a larger chunk of memory than initially requested (called the capacity) for just this reason.

Comment: Yes, but `std::vector` is an all purpose, standard library type.  It has to be capable of dealing with a vast array of use cases.  That's not what you're writing here.  You have the advantage of knowing precisely how your code will be used.

Comment: If you believe this is a concern in your program, implement both, profile, and make an informed decision.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This really depends on intricate memory details of your application. However, the guy's fundamental point is absolutely accurate- pre-allocation and memory regions are obscenely efficient. `new` and `delete` are the most general tools possible, and if you have a more specific problem, you can find a much more efficient solution. Fixed-size object pools are another example.

Answer (score 0):

It is. The operating system does not actually give you all that space anyway in some cases. Take Linux for example. Java tends to request large amounts of memory and never use it so what actually happens is that the OS keeps tracks of these ranges you requested but never maps them into the page tables (and therefore never allocates a frame for it) until you use it. So in terms of virtual memory it looks like you're using a lot but really you're only using the pages that you ever access (the 40kb in your example that you actually used). You can see this in the difference between virtual and physical usage of memory (assuming your processes aren't swapping out).